# JSON to Google Chart

Tags: mysql, json, google-visualization

I have the following JSON output. I want to make a combo chart using Google Chart which contains tool, month and grandtotal graph, so basically, the Y axis will be the count, X axis will be the month and the count per tool should be stacked side by side for the 4 months into consideration. The best I get out of this is count on the Y axis and tool on the x axis

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Tool","type":"string"},{"label":"Month","type":"number"},{"label":"GrandTotal","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"ARTS"},{"v":4},{"v":7907}]},{"c":[{"v":"MART"},{"v":4},{"v":7850}]},{"c":[{"v":"MART"},{"v":5},{"v":4394}]},{"c":[{"v":"ARTS"},{"v":6},{"v":3552}]},{"c":[{"v":"MART"},{"v":6},{"v":3358}]},{"c":[{"v":"ARTS"},{"v":7},{"v":3190}]},{"c":[{"v":"MART"},{"v":7},{"v":2835}]},{"c":[{"v":"ARTS"},{"v":5},{"v":2743}]},{"c":[{"v":"trol"},{"v":5},{"v":1297}]},{"c":[{"v":"Metrics"},{"v":4},{"v":1198}]},{"c":[{"v":"Metrics"},{"v":5},{"v":1161}]},{"c":[{"v":"GenericEv"},{"v":7},{"v":1094}]},{"c":[{"v":"trol"},{"v":7},{"v":1038}]},{"c":[{"v":"TM"},{"v":4},{"v":948}]},{"c":[{"v":"Center"},{"v":7},{"v":874}]},{"c":[{"v":"trol"},{"v":6},{"v":865}]},{"c":[{"v":"TM"},{"v":5},{"v":842}]},{"c":[{"v":"COM"},{"v":5},{"v":820}]},{"c":[{"v":"Metrics"},{"v":6},{"v":797}]},{"c":[{"v":"COM"},{"v":7},{"v":736}]},{"c":[{"v":"Metrics"},{"v":7},{"v":727}]},{"c":[{"v":"TM"},{"v":6},{"v":708}]},{"c":[{"v":"Center"},{"v":5},{"v":703}]},{"c":[{"v":"Center"},{"v":6},{"v":700}]},{"c":[{"v":"COM"},{"v":4},{"v":629}]},{"c":[{"v":"Disconnects"},{"v":5},{"v":578}]},{"c":[{"v":"trol"},{"v":4},{"v":560}]},{"c":[{"v":"COM"},{"v":6},{"v":545}]},{"c":[{"v":"NET"},{"v":5},{"v":496}]},{"c":[{"v":"Disconnects"},{"v":6},{"v":492}]},{"c":[{"v":"Center"},{"v":4},{"v":453}]},{"c":[{"v":"Disconnects"},{"v":4},{"v":414}]},{"c":[{"v":"NET"},{"v":7},{"v":352}]},{"c":[{"v":"NET"},{"v":4},{"v":335}]},{"c":[{"v":"GenericEv"},{"v":4},{"v":333}]},{"c":[{"v":"NET"},{"v":6},{"v":319}]},{"c":[{"v":"TM"},{"v":7},{"v":215}]},{"c":[{"v":"Disconnects"},{"v":7},{"v":155}]},{"c":[{"v":"Heartbeat"},{"v":5},{"v":127}]},{"c":[{"v":"WiFir"},{"v":6},{"v":117}]},{"c":[{"v":"GenericEv"},{"v":6},{"v":104}]},{"c":[{"v":"Heartbeat"},{"v":6},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Heartbeat"},{"v":7},{"v":76}]},{"c":[{"v":"WiFir"},{"v":5},{"v":74}]},{"c":[{"v":"Heartbeat"},{"v":4},{"v":71}]},{"c":[{"v":"WiFir"},{"v":7},{"v":71}]},{"c":[{"v":"QMan"},{"v":7},{"v":53}]},{"c":[{"v":"WiFir"},{"v":4},{"v":47}]},{"c":[{"v":"QMan"},{"v":4},{"v":46}]},{"c":[{"v":"QMan"},{"v":6},{"v":28}]},{"c":[{"v":"CustomP"},{"v":6},{"v":26}]},{"c":[{"v":"QMan"},{"v":5},{"v":25}]},{"c":[{"v":"GenericEv"},{"v":5},{"v":21}]},{"c":[{"v":"CustomP"},{"v":5},{"v":17}]},{"c":[{"v":"Gios"},{"v":7},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":"Gios"},{"v":5},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"NA"},{"v":7},{"v":4}]},{"c":[{"v":"HostMBLR"},{"v":6},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"NA"},{"v":4},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"HostMBLR"},{"v":7},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"HostMBLR"},{"v":4},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"CustomP"},{"v":4},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"NA"},{"v":5},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"HostMBLR"},{"v":5},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"NA"},{"v":6},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"Gios"},{"v":4},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"CustomP"},{"v":7},{"v":1}]}]}
```

Is there any way I can make this into that graph?
And to let you all know, I am querying the database taking this information out using the following MYSQL query.

```
    select tool as Tool,MonthValue as Month, count(tool) as GrandTotal FROM alerts group by month,tool order by grandtotal DESC
```

Or do I have to modify my query?

Please let me know

Thanks
Sash

Comment: Your first column should be month and then you need one column for each tool, with the tool name as column title and with the value of that tool for each month. Then you can set isStacked to true

Comment: Thanks Juvian, after a read, I have used this                                                                select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT month,"-",tool) as tool,
 count(*) as GrandTotal
 FROM alerts
 group by tool,MONTH . But now, the JSONtable isnt getting the data. Thoughts?

Comment: My query lacked '-'. Now it is fixed ..Thanks

Comment: Great you got it working, good luck with your project